# Laravel 4.2 rewrite URL - remove public

Tags: laravel-4

My old domain: **domain.com**

My laravel project in: **domain.com/laravel/public**
It's working well, but I don't want see public in URL.

I add new .htaccess file to my root laravel folder (**domain.com/laravel/.htaccess**) with:

    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

When I access to **domain.com/laravel**, my jQuery path is: **domain.com/js/jquery.min.js**

When I access to **domain.com/laravel/public**, my jQuery path is: **domain.com/laravel/public/js/jquery.min.js**

I don't want move all files in public folder to root folder, because really more files there.

Best regards,

Comment: The idea is to have all of the files in public in your site root, and all the other files outside of your site root. This has several advantages, especially around security.

Comment: Hi Marty, thank you for helping!

I have many files in public folder, I has more function read content from text file (I put in public folder), if I moving all files to public folder, this hard for me to maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I read more answers in more website, almost their said move all files in public folder to root folder of Laravel application.

It's not good if we have more files there, so, I was try with some way and finally, I just move index.php and .htaccess file to root application.

It's working well, I just change some code when using HTML::script, HTML::css and {{ asset }}
As normal, we using HTML::css('style.css'), I just add public before, like this: HTML::css('public/style.css')

I hope it helpful for someone.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond $1 !^(public)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You have to add a rewrite condition.