# Laravel .htaccess rewrite URL for removing public

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, public

I have a Laravel project

My domain is **domain.com.tw**

and the URL will be **domain.com.tw/public**,

and the page could be showed.

I want to remove the `public` in URL,

so I write `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it did not work for me
I had look at these also, but still failed

[Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)

[Laravel 4.2 rewrite URL - remove public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269780/laravel-4-2-rewrite-url-remove-public)

could someone tell me the solution? thanks!!

Comment: you are using laravel 4 or 5 if 5 you can move the .htaccess file inside the public directory outside to the root folder then rename the server.php file in the root folder to index.php

Comment: Hi I use Laravel 4.2 for this project, so the .htaccess was already outside with the root folder, is it also needed to rename server.php to index.php ?

Comment: in L5 it is so give it a try in L4

Comment: have a look at this http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1622

Comment: how about changing your document root in your apache config from "your/path/to/laravel" to "your/path/to/laravel/public"

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>  try only  this code in your htaccess

Comment: yep, I'd try move `.htaccess` (with RewriteRule writen inside) to the root and rename `server.php` to `index.php`, now the url `domain.com.tw` could show the page but without any style, seems that css, JS stuff in `public` could not be loaded?

Comment: how about not using htaccess and  using content moving I have given some idea as example try it

Comment: Yep, first thing I thought is to change the root folder setting, but the Server that customer payed for did not support changing HTTP SERVER Virtual Host. So I could not chang my document root...

Comment: then why not change you folder structure as I have answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder on root with named “whatever”(you can give any name).
Move all files except public folder in the “whatever” folder.
Move all the files of public to root directory and remove blank public folder.
so directory structure will be:

1. whatever– which have all root files except public folder
2. all files of public folder.

Now time to change some paths
in paths.php change the following code
`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'`, into `'public' => __DIR__.'/../../'`,

open index.php (on root) and find below code

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

change this to

```
require __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/local/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Hope this helps or at least give you some idea

Comment: yo thanks man, at last this solution is work for me by changing the `path.php` and `index.php`.

Comment: glad it was helpful to you @JasperChang